# php checkbox id = the mysql id

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a php/mysql page. I have the table displaying the results I want with a checkbox in front of each row, and I'm having difficulty labeling the id/name of the checkbox the row id from the query that I've done. I have tried looking at this, and have seen several examples that it's possible but wasn't able to see the code. Any help would be appreciated. I have this code:

```
    for ( $counter = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result );$counter++ ){

           // build table to display results

           print( "<tr>" ); 

           print("<td> <input type='checkbox' name='$row['id']' value='". $row['id'] ."'> </td>");

           foreach ( $row as $key => $value ) 
              print( "<td>$value</td>" );

           print( "</tr>" );
        }
```

Comment: You're concatenating the `value` - why not do the same for `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a lot of things wrong.

Look the "for" structure.

The correct is:

```
for($conter = 0; $counter < count(mysql_fetch_row( $result ); $counter++)
...
```

Or you can use this:

```
foreach(mysql_fetch_row($result) as $row){
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='$row['id']' value='$row['id']'></td>";
}
```